# Action Creator return undefined axios

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, axios

Can successfully register the user using my action creator but it returns undefined. I think it's the way how am returning my dispatch

axiosInstance

```
import axios from 'axios';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
// import base url
import {API_URL} from '../constants';

const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: API_URL,
    timeout: 2000,

});

instance.interceptors.request.use(
    async(config) => {
        const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
        if(token) {
            config.headers.Autherization = `${token}`;
        }
        return config;
    },`enter code here`
    (err) => {
        return Promise.reject(err);
    }
)


export default instance;
```

SignUP Action.

```
import axiosInstance from '../../api/axiosInstance';
import {REGISTER_USER_SUCCESS, REGISTER_USER_FAIL} from '../actionTypes/index';

const registerSuccess = (payload) => {
    return{
        type: REGISTER_USER_SUCCESS,
        data: payload
    }
};

const registerError = (payload) => {
    return {
        type: REGISTER_USER_FAIL,
        data: payload
    }
};

export const SignUp = (registerData) => async dispatch => {
    axiosInstance.post('/users/register', registerData)
      .then((response)=> {
        dispatch(registerSuccess(response.data));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        dispatch(registerError(error));
      });
}
```

Here is how am using my action creator .. the result is undefined . I want to have a check some that I can redirect the screen to another login screen or home screen

SignUP Submit function

```
      dispatch(registerAction.SignUp(values))
        .then( (result) => {
          console.log('klhadsghaj',result.status);
          if(result.success) {
            try {
              navData.navigation.navigate("Login");
            }catch (err) {
              console.log(err)
            }

          } else {
            Alert.alert('Registration failed. Try Again')
          }   
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Comment: You are not returning in SignUp: `return axiosInstance.post('/users/register', registerData)` and `return dispatch(registerSuccess(response.data)); `

Comment: Thanks, forgot to return